# Solutions to do referrer based advertising?

Tags: ads, referrer

This a bit of a weird question so please let me know if you need more information.

For a side project I am working on I need to ability to generate advertising on a specific page based on a specified domain. I have looked a bit and haven't found anything that really fits this so I'm hoping someone here has a service like this or can push me in the correct direction. I'm not super interested in finding my own advertiser/rolling my own solution currently (not to say it wont happen in the future), looking for more of an out of the box solution.

Clarification: The advertising content on this page will be generated based upon the referral URL. So in other words instead of the advertising content being contextual to the page it is delivered on.. it is contextual to a domain/URL.

TYIA

Answer (score 0):

I assume You are working with it the way Adsense works - a javascript makes an ajax call to a PHP file stored on your server which returns the content, which is afterwards added to the page.
In such case I can think of two ways:
1. Use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], which won't always work;
2. Or send the current page address (window.location.href if I recall correctly) with the ajax call

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm pretty sure I could create my own solution doing it this way. Problem is then I have to throw the time into not only building the solution but finding the advertisers. I'm hoping to find something that already exists (hopefully a service that supports this)